# Login challenge missing after migrating asp website from .net 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I'm upgrading an old internal website from .net 2 to 4 using [this procedure from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx).
I mostly got rid of .net assembly references in the web.config and switched the DefaultAppPool. However when I tried to access the website  using http://localhost/ the login challenge didn't show up.  `Request.LogonUserIdentity` Is being used to get credentials.

When I use http: //localhost/auth.aspx  the Challenge *does* come up. IIS manager has the auth.apx page set as default and I know for a fact it's being used, but the authentication doesn't show up unless I directly address it.

Any ideas as to why it would only work when i type the full address? (If i go back to using .net 2.0 the request shows up without the full address, it only seems to happen on 4.0)

Comment: Is your app pool configured to use .NET 4?